# While loop to find square root of a number until it is less than or equal to 1.01

Tags: java, math

I need help implementing a while loop that takes a user input as a double or int(not sure) and square roots it until it has reached less than or equal to 1.01.

Example: `Math.sqrt(10.5)`

```
1. Calculated square root is --> 3.24037034920393
2. Calculated square root is --> 1.8001028718392542
3. Calculated square root is --> 1.3416791240230483
4. Calculated square root is --> 1.1583087343290857
5. Calculated square root is --> 1.0762475246564267
6. Calculated square root is --> 1.0374235030383814
7. Calculated square root is --> 1.0185398877993839
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SquareRoot {

    public static void main (String args[]){
        final double SENTINEL = 10;
        int count = 0;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double userInput; // input value

        do
        {
            System.out.println( "Enter a number greater than 10"  );
            userInput = scan.nextDouble( );
        } while ( userInput <= 1 || userInput >= 10 );


        double squareRoot = Math.sqrt(userInput);
        double resultSquareRoot = Math.sqrt(squareRoot);

        while (resultSquareRoot <= 1.01){
            resultSquareRoot = Math.sqrt(squareRoot);

        }
        System.out.println(resultSquareRoot);


    }

}
```

Comment: What problems are you experiencing?

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: Read your condition carefully. What does `while (resultSquareRoot <= 1.01){` do?

Comment: You aren't changing the value of `Math.sqrt(squareRoot)` because `squareRoot` doesn't change in your loop.

Comment: When asking a question that requires debugging help, you need to explain what the expected behavior is and **how that differs from what you're currently getting**

Comment: *"Enter a number greater than 10"*, followed by `while(userInput >= 10)` doesn't make sense. You are punishing them for following instructions. And what's the `userInput <= 1` for?

Comment: This is where stepping through the code in your debugger should show you the problem faster than asking on SO.

Comment: The while condition being true keeps looping. For an input above 10 use `do { ... } while (userInput <= 10);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to note in your solution, why are trying to call the below lines of code in do-while.
Not needed as your intent is to do apply Math.sqrt till the entered number square reaches to 1.01, hence we are talking about looping here.

System.out.println( "Enter a number greater than 10"  );
            userInput = scan.nextDouble();

Also you don't need a second while loop.

```
while (resultSquareRoot <= 1.01){
            resultSquareRoot = Math.sqrt(squareRoot);

        }
```

What is missing in your code is the break condition.

This can be achieved with below lines of code.

```
    do {
         userInput = Math.sqrt(userInput);
        System.out.println("Calculated square root is -->"+userInput);
        if(userInput<= 1.01)
            break;
    } while (userInput >= 1.01 );
```

### output

```
Calculated square root is -->3.24037034920393
Calculated square root is -->1.8001028718392542
Calculated square root is -->1.3416791240230483
Calculated square root is -->1.1583087343290857
Calculated square root is -->1.0762475246564267
Calculated square root is -->1.0374235030383814
Calculated square root is -->1.0185398877993839
Calculated square root is -->1.0092273717053972
```

Comment: Explain your answer too; don't just dump code. It is of little help.

Comment: @Tibrogargan.. what if the logic has a problem. also tell  me what is the significant change

Answer (score 2):

Your loop:

```
while (resultSquareRoot <= 1.01){
    resultSquareRoot = Math.sqrt(squareRoot);
}
System.out.println(resultSquareRoot);
```

Should be:

```
while (resultSquareRoot > 1.01){
    System.out.println("Calculated square root is --> " + resultSquareRoot);
    resultSquareRoot = Math.sqrt(resultSquareRoot);
}
```

You are not changing the value of the parameter to `Math.sqrt`, and thus `resultSquareRoot` never changes.

You want `resultSquareRoot = Math.sqrt(resultSquareRoot);`

instead of `resultSquareRoot = Math.sqrt(squareRoot);`

Comment: Fixed it - I had just copied it from the OP

Comment: No the condition is already resultSquareRoot you're just nuts

Comment: My point is that, in addition to the condition being flawed, the OP did not change the value of `resultSquareRoot`, so the loop would never end.

Comment: Read the you want... part of his answer

Comment: @joepelletier I still don't understand what you're trying to say. What's wrong with that part of my answer?

Comment: @MistahFiggins The result of `Math.sqrt(squareRoot)` is invariant.  Plus, the output of your code doesn't match the example output

Comment: @Tibrogargan That's my point. It doesn't change, so he needs to fix that line of code. And now my answer should match the output.

Comment: @MistahFiggins lol I did not realize that that was your answer. I thought you were saying the answer was wrong and I was defending it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change

```
 while (resultSquareRoot <= 1.01){
        resultSquareRoot = Math.sqrt(squareRoot);

    }
```

to

```
 while (resultSquareRoot > 1.01){
        resultSquareRoot = Math.sqrt(resultSquareRoot );

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The do while condition is wrong. It should be:

```
do
    {
     System.out.println( "Enter a number greater than 10"  );
     userInput = scan.nextDouble( );
    } while ( userInput <= 10 );
```

And the while condition is also wrong. Pls check code below:

```
public static void main (String args[]){
        final double SENTINEL = 10;
        int count = 0;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double userInput; // input value

        do
        {
            System.out.println( "Enter a number greater than 10"  );
            userInput = scan.nextDouble( );
        } while ( userInput <= 10 );

        double resultSquareRoot = userInput;

        while (resultSquareRoot >= 1.01){
            resultSquareRoot = Math.sqrt(resultSquareRoot);

        }
        System.out.println(resultSquareRoot);


    }
```

Comment: How would a number safisfy `<= 1` and `>= 10` at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for a number greater than 10, so you should have

```
do
{
    System.out.println( "Enter a number greater than 10"  );
    userInput = scan.nextDouble( );
} while ( userInput < 10 );
```

because you want to keep asking for a number while it is smaller than 10.

Then here, you're always doing the `Math.sqrt(squareRoot)` and storing it in `resultSquareRoot`, so you're always getting the same value in `resultSquareRoot` inside the while loop, because you're never changing the value of `squareRoot`. And you want your condition to run `while it is greater than 1.01`

```
double squareRoot = Math.sqrt(userInput);
double resultSquareRoot = Math.sqrt(squareRoot);

while (resultSquareRoot > 1.01){
    resultSquareRoot = Math.sqrt(resultSquareRoot);
}
System.out.println(resultSquareRoot);
```